# Extract a field from nested json in a splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

This is the data I have:

```
{ "a":"1",
  "b":2,
  "c": { "x":"3", "y":"4",}
}
```

let's suppose I have tons of events in that format. What I want to do is to write a query that will only extract "x"s from all events. I don't want anything else to be returned, just the "x"s.

I've tried multiple examples and I went through pages of documentation and yet I still did not succeed with this, there must be something I'm missing. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what you've tried so far and how those attempts failed to meet expectations.

Have you tried the `rex` command?

```
| rex max_match=0 "\\\"x\\\":\\\"(?<x>[^\\\"]+)"
```

The forest of backslashes is needed to escape the embedded quotation marks through multiple parsers.

Comment: OK, so if I do this:
| table a
-> the result is a table with all values of "a"

If I do this:
| table a c.x
-> the result is not all values of "x" as I expected, but an empty column.

Then if I try this:
| spath path=c.x output=myfield | table myfield

the result is also an empty column.

Comment: The OP asked about extracting 'x', not 'c.x'. There's a difference.  In my sandbox, `| spath | table c.x` returned "3" using the sample event.

Comment: So, if I use `| spath input=_raw output=foo path=c | table foo`, I get a table with Xs and Ys. But if I use `| spath input=_raw output=foo path=c.x | table foo` I get a completely empty column.

Answer (score 0):

This query works for me.  Note the missing comma after the "y" value.  Splunk will produce unexpected results if the JSON is not valid.

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="{ \"a\":\"1\",
  \"b\":2,
  \"c\": { \"x\":\"3\", \"y\":\"4\"}
}"
| spath output=foo path=c.x
| table foo
```